# How to set starting image of jCarousel based on mouse click of separate image gallery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jcarousel

I have a page which contains a jCarousel slider (in a div) and a div which contains a list of thumbnails. The carousel is hidden on initial load of the page, while the the thumbnails are visible. What I'm trying to achieve is when the user clicks on a specific thumbnail, the list of thumbnails (or gallery, i should say) fades out while the carousel becomes visible WITH the larger version of the image of the clicked thumbnail shown first on the carousel. I've tried setting the carousel's configuration option "start" to a variable that contains the clicked thumbnail id, but that gave me odd results. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Here's my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var currImage;
    $('#carousel').hide();
    $('.thumb').click(function(){
        $('#thumbs').fadeOut('slow');
        currImage = $(this).attr('id');

        $('#mycarousel').jcarousel({
            start: currImage,
            visible: 1,
            scroll: 1  
        });
        $('#carousel').fadeIn('slow');      
    }); 
});
</script>
<div id="thumbs">
    <ul class="thumb-display">
        <li>
            <a class="thumb" href="#" id="1">
                <img src="pic1-thumb.jpg" />
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="thumb" href="#" id="2">
                <img src="pic2-thumb.jpg" />
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="carousel">
    <ul id="mycarousel" class="jcarousel-skin-tango">
        <li><img src="pic1-large/></li>
        <li><img src="pic2-large/></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pphou, your intended use of jCarousel is very similar to the [Carousel with External Controls](http://file://localhost/C:/Users/adrian/Documents/daniweb/jquery/jcarousel-0.2.8/examples/static_controls.html) example.

The trick is to set up your thumbnails as external controls in an `initCallback` function.

The code will be something like this:

javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $thumbs = $('#thumbs');
    $carousel = $('#mycarousel').hide();
    $carousel.jcarousel({
        visible: 1,
        scroll: 1,
        initCallback: function(carousel) {
            $thumbs.find('a').on('click', function() {
                carousel.scroll($.jcarousel.intval($(this).attr('id')));
//              carousel.scroll($.jcarousel.intval($(this).index()));//may work, if so then omit ids from the HTML
                $thumbs.fadeOut('slow');
                $carousel.fadeIn('slow');
                return false;
            });
        }
    });
});
```

*untested*

You may need to play with the code a bit to get exactly what you want.

You will also need to establish a way back to the thumbnails from the carousel. I have not addressed this aspect.

Remember to number the thumbnail ids from 0 (zero) as gregL points out.

Comment: thanks so much for the help! I've followed your suggestion and I'm a step closer, but the problem now is that the carousel is visible on initial load. Everything else works fine. I've tried tweaking the code a bit, but it's not getting me anywhere.

Comment: That's probably because my code addresses only `#mycarousel` and not `#carousel`. Try `$carousel = $('#carousel').hide();` and `$mycarousel = $('#mycarousel');` at the top of the function, then you have the means of controlling the container and the carousel itself independently. There's also a `$` missing at lines 9 and 10 of my code but you probably spotted that. If you still can't get it working, try creating a jsfidle of it (or a simplification) so I have something to play with.

Comment: Correction - I didn't miss a $ at lines 9/10. It was right first time. I have set up a fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/sbbm4/2/

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH Beetroot!!! It works like a charm now. Excellent solution! I had a difficult time understanding the jCarousel documentation and was really confused about its parameters and what to plug in. Also, much thanks for introducing me to jsFiddle. Very useful tool! :)

Comment: @pphou There's no shame in not understanding jCarousel documentation - it could be better. I found the examples' source to be the best way to learn.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the simple answer is that `start` is 0-based, not 1-based.

So try using:

```
    $('#mycarousel').jcarousel({
        start: currImage - 1,
        visible: 1,
        scroll: 1  
    });
```

to initialise the jCarousel.

Alternatively, can the plugin determine the dimensions of the images correctly? If not, try adding explicit `height` and `width` attributes or CSS styles.

Also, IDs are probably not best as "1", "2" and so on. Use a `data-imagenum` attribute or similar instead.

Comment: Thanks mate, but that suggestion didn't have any effect.